# Plotting Simple Data in R

Tags: r, plot

I have a comma separated file named `foo.csv` containing the following data:

```
scale, serial, spawn, for, worker
5, 0.000178, 0.000288, 0.000292, 0.000300
10, 0.156986, 0.297926, 0.064509, 0.066297
12, 2.658998, 6.059502, 0.912733, 0.923606
15, 188.023411, 719.463264, 164.111459, 161.687982
```

I essentially have two questions:

1) How do I plot the first column (x-axis) versus the second column (y-axis)? I'm trying this (from reading [this site](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/R/gbe/scatter.htm)):

```
data <- read.table("foo.csv", header=T,sep=",")
attach(data)
scale <- data[1]
serial <- data[2]
plot(scale,serial)
```

But I get this error back:

```
Error in stripchart.default(x1, ...) : invalid plotting method
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? A [quick Google search](http://www.nabble.com/Problems-producing-a-simple-plot-td23347296.html) reveals someone else with the same problem but no relevant answer. UPDATE: It turns out it works fine if I skip the two assignment statements in the middle. Any idea why this is?

The second question follows pretty easily after the first:

2) How do I plot the first column (x-axis) versus all the other columns on the y-axis? I presume it's pretty easy once I get around the first problem I'm running into, but am just a bit new to R so I'm still wrapping my head around it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You don't need the two lines:

```
scale <- data[1]
serial <- data[2]
```

as scale and serial are already set from the headers in the `read.table`.

Also `scale <- data[1]` creates an element from a `data.frame`

```
  data[1]
1     5
2    10
3    12
4    15
```

whereas `scale` from the `read.table` is a vector

```
5 10 12 15
```

and the `plot(scale, serial)` function expects vector rather than a data.frame, so you just need to do

```
plot(scale, serial)
```

One approach to plotting the other columns of data on the y-axis:

```
plot(scale,serial, ylab="")
par(new=TRUE) 
plot(scale,spawn,axes=F, ylab="", type="b")
par(new=TRUE) 
plot(scale,for., axes=F, ylab="", type="b")
par(new=TRUE) 
plot(scale,worker,axes=F, ylab="", type="b")
```

There are probably better ways of doing this, but that is beyond my current R knowledge....

Comment: So what should his plot() call look like?

Comment: Unfortunately, "scale" seems to be a global of some sort.

Comment: I think it should be ok (the above all works fine on my R anyway :)). The scale variable will be set from the read.table, and it should not interfere with the "global" scale() function.

Answer (score 7):

In your example,

```
plot(scale, serial)
```

won't work because `scale` and `serial` are both data frames, e.g.

```
class(scale)
[1] "data.frame"
```

You could try the following and use `points()`, once the plot has been generated, to plot the remaining columns.  Note, I used the `ylim` parameter in `plot` to accommodate the range in the third column.

```
data <- read.csv('foo.csv', header=T)
plot(data$scale, data$serial, ylim=c(0,750))
points(data$scale, data$spawn, col='red')
points(data$scale, data$for., col='green')
points(data$scale, data$worker, col='blue')
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm new in R, but if you want to draw scale vs. all other columns in one plot, easy and with some elegance :) for printing or presentation, you may use Prof. Hadley Wickham's packages ggplot2 & reshape.

Installation:

```
install.packages(“ggplot2”,dep=T)
install.packages(“reshape”,dep=T)
```

Drawing your example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape)

#read data
data = read.table("foo.csv", header=T,sep=",")

#melt data “scale vs. all”
data2=melt(data,id=c("scale"))
data2

   scale variable      value
1      5   serial   0.000178
2     10   serial   0.156986
3     12   serial   2.658998
4     15   serial 188.023411
5      5    spawn   0.000288
6     10    spawn   0.297926
7     12    spawn   6.059502
8     15    spawn 719.463264
9      5     for.   0.000292
10    10     for.   0.064509
11    12     for.   0.912733
12    15     for. 164.111459
13     5   worker   0.000300
14    10   worker   0.066297
15    12   worker   0.923606
16    15   worker 161.687982

#draw all variables at once as line with different linetypes
qplot(scale,value,data=data2,geom="line",linetype=variable)
```

You could also use points (`geom=”points”`), choose different colours or shapes for different variables dots (`colours=variable or shape=variable`), adjust axis, set individual options for every line etc.

Link to [online documentation](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/).

Answer (score 2):

I am far from being an R expert, but I think you need a data.frame:

```
plot(data.frame(data[1],data[2]))
```

It does at least plot something on my R setup!

Following advice in luapyad's answer, I came up with this. I renamed the header "scale":

```
scaling, serial, spawn, for, worker
5, 0.000178, 0.000288, 0.000292, 0.000300
10, 0.156986, 0.297926, 0.064509, 0.066297
12, 2.658998, 6.059502, 0.912733, 0.923606
15, 188.023411, 719.463264, 164.111459, 161.687982
```

then:

```
foo <- read.table("foo.csv", header=T,sep=",")
attach(foo)
plot( scaling, serial );
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
data <- read.csv('foo.csv')
plot(serial ~ scale, data)
dev.new()
plot(spawn ~ scale, data)
dev.new()
plot(for. ~ scale, data)
dev.new()
plot(worker ~ scale, data)
```

Comment: you could combine the 4 plots into one graphic by using either matplot(data[1],data[2,5],type="b") or with the individual plot commands preceded by layout(matrix(c(1,2,3,4),2,2,byrow=TRUE))

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple-r way of plotting it:

https://code.google.com/p/simple-r/

Using that script, you just have to type:

```
r -cdps, -k1:2 foo.csv
```

To get the plot you want. Put it in the verbose mode (-v) to see the corresponding R script.

Answer (score 0):

```
data <- read.table(...)
plot(data$scale,data$serial)
```