# Plotting a graph in Linux (Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, plot, large-data-volumes

I have a file containing large amount of data (3.5GB, about 100M records, one repord per line). Format of a record is: `<time> <label> <magnitude>`. Format of time is: `HH:mm:ss.000`

I want to get a plot with points from file put on it (axis X: time, axis Y: magnitude, point color depends on label [not necessary but will be very good]).

What it the ways of plotting such a graph?

Comment: [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/) comes into mind.

Comment: [Matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/) and [gnuplot](http://gnuplot.info) are two excellent options. They're even cross-platform.

Comment: python-matplolib: nicer syntax... better control, and more ... hmm... well python ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The 'R' programming language is built for tasks like this. Take a look [here](http://www.cyclismo.org/tutorial/R/plotting.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876711/plotting-simple-data-in-r).